# Footer does not stick to bottom of page

Tags: feature-request, bug, status-declined, design

OK, sorry, I know this is really superficial, but look at this page:

> [https://stackoverflow.com/a/page/that/does/not/exist/number/1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/page/that/does/not/exist/number/11)

See the giant, ugly, horrible white space below the footer that burns into your eyes?
You can use this website to fix it (note - I am not associated with this website in any way): http://www.cssstickyfooter.com/

---

Jeff - I need an answer. Please?

Comment: *puts tape on the bottom of the footer*

Comment: @Paolo Bergantino: I think this is a bug, not a feature - the way this site is designed I would think this is how it is supposed to be.

Comment: I'm not going to roll it back, but this is not a bug, and it's not even close. Do you honestly think Jeff (or anyone in the staff, for that matter) has never noticed that's how short pages look? They re obviously aware of it and it is obviously not important to them or they would have done it by now. So this is a feature request.

Comment: I agree, i think this is a feature request.

Comment: What is the new feature? It should be a bug. The feature 'footer' is implemented. The fact that it appears in the wrong place is a bug

Comment: redsquare: I disagree. The footer is showing in the right place: after the content. Sticky footers are definitely in the feature realm of things.

Comment: I think this is a bug. The footer is supposed to show at the bottom of the screen. The only page that is really short enough to see the effect is the about page on Meta Stack Overflow, because they hardly put anything there.

Comment: Maybe compromise and use the tag bug-request? Wait, maybe not.

Comment: considering that bug database and the feature database are one and the same, does it really matter how it's tagged?

Comment: Ascribing "footer" the meaning of "bottom of the screen" is entirely subjective, how is that not obvious?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We looked at this, but the so-called "fix" is really nasty and involves a lot of kludgy, hacky layout. And lots of lines of it.

Kind of a case where the cure is worse than the disease.

Comment: OK Jeff, you win once more.

Comment: I don't like it either, but I'm running into a lot of "cure worse than disease" issues lately.

Answer (score 1):

That's the only page I recall seeing this problem on.. And even still it's a very minor annoyance (how often do you really view the About page? Once, *maybe*)

Is the extra 35 lines of CSS really worth it? Perhaps a better solution would be to make the About page a little more verbose? Mentioning something about the site effectively being the [SO bug tracking/feature request system](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1/should-meta-stackoverflow-com-replace-uservoice-com)  for one

Comment: Here is another one http://stackoverflow.com/about/contact

Answer (score 1):

Again, this is easily fixable with stylish or greasemonkey. Your personal taste is exactly that.

Answer (score -1):

The same thing happens on the "recent activity" page when there has been very little activity.  See this [ticket I opened in uservoice](https://web.archive.org/web/20090430205439/http://stackoverflow.uservoice.com:80/pages/general/suggestions/111210-keep-footer-at-the-bottom-of-the-screen) a long while ago: