# Can we do something better with the footer?

Tags: feature-request

I always notice when a page isn't quite vertically long enough to fill my entire browser. Examples are the users page (viewed on 1280x1024) but there are plenty more. I think Stack Overflow would benefit by changing the way the footer works in some way.

It might work to extend the grey footer color to the bottom of the screen *OR* stick the footer to the bottom of the screen so we don't get white-space after it.

I'd be interested to hear opinions.

Comment: I just don't see the long footer as being a win, by my screens are wide and short, so it is a non-issue for me...

Comment: Vertical space works well with stackoverflow on the front page etc.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1330/footer-does-not-stick-to-bottom-of-page

Answer (score 2):

I am not terribly happy with the current status quo ... but some of the "sticky footer" solutions seem really nasty, [much worse than the problem itself](http://ryanfait.com/resources/footer-stick-to-bottom-of-page/).

Open to input, but I don't want crazy CSS hax.

edit: Actually, taking another look, that one doesn't look too hacky. The last time I looked at this, I recall being unpleasantly surprised...

Answer (score 1):

I think you should try seeing the world through 1050x1680 (portrait). You get used to it reallll quick, and it's soo not a big deal.

Comment: +1! My Internet monitor at work is always in portrait orientation;  sites tend to be designed for limited width but infinite height. (Still using landscape for the code monitor.)