# Footer is not styled at the bottom in chat

Tags: bug, chat, design

I recently visited a page on chat and see that the footer doesn't stick to the bottom of the page. I don't think it is intentional. There is a lot space under the footer which doesn't look all that great.

> [image]

Why not remove all the background styles from the footer and make all of the pages match what you'd see on [Meta SE Chat](http://chat.meta.stackexchange.com)? Then the footer can just be at the bottom and wouldn't look funky anymore.

> [image: No More Funky]

Comment: That's the spaces that is _under_ the footer. Are you trying to say that the footer should be fixed to the bottom of the view port (and leave a huge space above it)?

Comment: @Oded ... well, it's a footer.

Comment: @Bart - That, it is. I'll let Jin weigh in on this one.

Comment: Yes, I just want to say footer should stick at the bottom of the page and yes in that case we can have white space above it. I think that makes a better look as compare to this.

Comment: possible duplicate http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/34281/can-we-do-something-better-with-the-footer?lq=1