# Meta Footer Layout Misplacement

Tags: bug, design, footer

I was browsing the meta footer and I saw a strange white space underneath the footer.

[image]

Should it be there, and if yes, why?

**EDIT:** As you can see this happens on Chrome. I also tested in IE and Firefox and it has the same effect.

Comment: well i think this is because of the UI design rule where you need space or it looks bad .. just look how reddit sucks without the right space

Comment: Who and why defined this rule, can you give some reference to it? Additionally, why is it here but not on Stack Overflow or any other Exchange sub-sites? Where is the consistency?

Comment: It's related to `#footer.categories #svnrev { margin-bottom: 10px; }`. MSE seems to have `#footer { padding: 0 }` instead of `15px` on other sites.

Comment: maybe they want MSE to show itself visually differently i don't know very much. **EDIT**:  now that i look deeper it seems a design bug

Comment: I'm not sure but there's a possibility you will get an answer like this one http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/23566/270297