# What features would you like to see in Blog Overflow?

Tags: discussion, voting, blog, blog-overflow

I like the StackOverflow interface so much I am now disappointed when I go to a blog and cannot vote up or down groups of comments. It bugs me even more when I go to https://blog.stackoverflow.com or [Coding Horror](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/) and the site just seem off. I am hoping that Jeff and Joel hire someone like they did for [Stack Exchange](http://www.stackexchange.com/) and adapt the engine for blogging.

Comment: related feature request: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18348/power-the-blog-content-and-discussion-with-meta-instead-of-wordpress

Answer (score 14):

Voting is clearly important, but I'd also love to be able to use markdown, particularly for coding blogs.

Comment: I've been using LiveWriter and writing code in VS or SnippetCompiler then inserting via a code plugin that also does syntax highlighting.  I find this actually easier than using markdown for blogging, primarily because I want to make sure the code works anyway before posting it.

Comment: @tvanfosson: I use LiveWriter and my own formatter, but I *constantly* miss markdown. Obviously I'd want to test any big bits of code, but just formatting a couple of lines, markdown's a heck of a lot simpler.

Comment: I hate it when my blog post content contains anything non-semantic like hundreds of little styling tips for code, I find the javascript based highlighter work fantastically, and ended up using one of those on my blog

Answer (score 3):

When I blog, it typically takes a little while to phrase it (especially if I need to add attachments). I suspect you'd need pending posts (visible to the author only) that you can edit incrementally before finally publishing it.

If you wanted to get fancy, delayed publish so you can blog while on holiday ;-p

Answer (score 2):

My number one request would be for having groups of comments be like an answer and be able to vote up and down the comment.

Answer (score 2):

Attachments ([here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4376/please-allow-image-uploads-directly-onto-the-site)|[here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4637/please-add-a-system-to-allow-file-uploads-attached-to-questions-and-answers)) - or at least, a simplified process for doing an upload+link in a single operation.

Answer (score 2):

I'd like the syntax highlighting to be smarter, particularly I'd like it to be language aware and let me choose from various languages so that keywords, etc. are highlighted better.  For example I'd like to be able to choose to highlight some parts of the entry as HTML, C#, or Javascript or mixed (MVC views, for instance).

Answer (score 0):

Ideally, this would be a WordPress plugin which supported both threaded comments and comment voting.  In a perfect world, it'd even support point-based reputation that gave commenters increased moderation abilities.

Anyone could just drop the plugin into their WordPress, and automatically get SO-style comment voting/threading/moderation.

Markdown could be offered as a separate WordPress plugin...  in fact, I think one's already available:
http://michelf.com/projects/php-markdown/