# Add the blog title to the new blog tooltip

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, blog, tooltips

The new blog notice in the header is quite nifty - especially the xx hours ago tooltip.

It could be useful to include the blog title and author in the tooltip as well:

> 14 hours ago - Improved Tagging, by Jeff Atwood

Comment: [The whole world](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/101315/make-the-new-blog-message-disappear-after-reading-it) ( *may be not the whole world but most of them* ) hates the big red icon and here you are asking for  a feature-request... You are a brave person...

Comment: Perhaps the whole world would hate it less if it was better...? I would even like the enhanced tooltip if the big red icon returned to the footer to be honest. It's less about the icon and more about the information it provides.

Comment: This isn't mutually exclusive with making the icon disappear *once you've read it*. This is still a good idea.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Good idea -- I made it so that we pull the latest blog entry title and author at the same time we pull the blog entry date.

So the tooltip should now be of the form

> Improved Tagging, by Jeff Atwood - 14 hours ago

Once we build again.

Comment: And it's live - i trust my cheque is in the mail