# New blog indicator - make it disappear everywhere after clicking

Tags: feature-request, notifications, blog

I check out several stackexchange sites on a regular basis and some of them will have the new blog indicator on the footer (or header) at the same time, for the same blog post (SO and Programmers mostly will have this, as would Meta on occasion).

Similarly to [this request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/101315/make-the-new-blog-message-disappear-after-reading-it), could you make this indicator disappear on *all* SE sites I am logged into once I have clicked on it from one?

That is, if I click on the blog indicator on SO, I don't want to see it still there on Programmers.

Comment: Likely to be rejected, read all the comments on the answer to the other post.  Plus it would need to be per-blog, not network wide -- many sites have individual blogs.

Comment: We'll keep an eye on this request...it's simply not a trivial change from the performance side.  Also, not all the blog links go to the same place.

Comment: @NickCraver Yikes, I forgot the bade also signals per-site blog entries. You definitely wouldn't want to dismiss a per-site blog indicator when someone reads the Stack Exchange blog.