# I get it! There's a new blog post?

Tags: bug

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [New blog indicator - make it disappear everywhere after clicking](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/109125/new-blog-indicator-make-it-disappear-everywhere-after-clicking)

Every time there's a new blog post, the ["new" icon](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/73879/how-new-is-a-blog-post) appears next to the "blog" link.  Awesome!  I read the blog and the icon goes away.  Cool.  Then I browse over to the meta on another StackExchange site.  Look at that: the blog is busy today.  I follow the link... and it's the same post I just saw.  Rinse and repeat for all the StackExchange sites you might follow and you'll quickly feel that stupid indicator is just crying wolf.

Can this be fixed so that if you dismiss it on one site, it's dismissed everywhere?

Comment: LOL at the !->? changer.

Comment: @John: Either one works as it turns out.  (But the "feature" sure is dumb.)