# tag-based blogs?

Tags: feature-request

I think it may be neat to have a feature where we can turn awesome answers into tag-specific blogs.

I used to read a few blogs but eventually authors start talking about other things that aren't what brought me in. Eventually blog authors branch out and start writing about their own cool stuff (case in point: Jeff doesn't write about SQL joins these days).

It's hard to find cool blogs, but stack-overflow generates a reasonable size of quality posts from different people. Sure, many questions are along the lines of "[Can I haz chezeburger in lolcode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8106474/what-does-mean)", but then we see [answers of high quality](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/3611/sql-injection-but-why-isnt-escape-quotes-safe-anymore/3633#3633) Which are technically interesting and great reads.

Sure we may already be promoting some posts to some degree, but **I feel a tag-specific-blog could encourage more interesting posts and [showcase the existing ones we already have](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454)**. Further more, I don't really care about everything on our existing blogs, I'd just like to get a nice digest of things from the technologies I do care about.

We could of course set up an automatic nomination system, where people who have gold/silver/bronze badges for those tags can nominate posts for going to the blog.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is already a proposal for enhancing the Community Blogs to be more available and and easier for user to contribute to. See [Using the Stack engine for the blog – a long-term idea for maintaining a healthy blogging culture](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/110998/using-the-stack-engine-for-the-blog-a-long-term-idea-for-maintaining-a-healthy).

If this were implemented, then it would be much easier to turn an answer into a blog post. You could then follow specific tags *on the blog* the same way you do on the normal site. There would be a degree of oversight and editing in terms of what gets published, but a site-run blog is a great way to promote interesting posts.

If you have more specific ideas about how your suggestions/features could be built into a more comprehensive blogging platform, please leave your comments or an answer on the linked post above!