# Move the Stack Exchange blog to blog.stackexchange.com

Tags: discussion, feature-request, stack-exchange, blog

With the development of Blog Overflow and allowing the Stack Exchange sites to create their own blogs, I was wondering why we in the Stack Overflow community don't have the rights to blog.

In addition, why is the Stack Exchange blog on Stack Overflow?  My suggestion is to please remove the company blog from Stack Overflow and actually put it where it belongs - on the main Stack Exchange site.

New comers to stackoverflow who want to read a blog about programming click "Blog" and they are presented with a blog about bicycles, math, and photography.  Logically it doesn't make sense.  I can understand that in the beginning the company was "Stack Overflow" but now it is Stack Exchange so we should definitely move the blog to the Stack Exchange website.

Thoughts / comments?

Comment: Stack Exchange is a Q&A network, not a blog network. If every single member of a Q&A site were allowed to contribute to a single blog, or worse, keep blogs of their own...

Comment: @BoltClock'saUnicorn - did you read my request?  I am not saying it is a blog network.  I am saying the things that are being discussed on the "blog" link on the stackoverflow site refer to information about StackExchange and not directly with stack overflow - it doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 4):

I agree with this.  `blog.stackexchange.com` may *work*, but the favicon, for example, is still SO's logo not SE's.  To me, this lends it a great deal of identity as SO's blog, not SE's, when it reality, it encompasses all of SE.

Sure if we wanted to we could go and read random fitness and gaming blogs, but we try to aggregate good posts here on blogs to go with our fitness and gaming sites anyway.

I propose that the official SE blog be located exclusively at `blog.stackexchange.com`, and that a community powered blog be started for Stack Overflow like the other sites have.

Of course, on a massive site like SO, I would imagine it would be difficult to have the blog run by 10 people who meet in a chat room once in a while with an admin link to a WordPress dashboard.

[Vast improvements have already been proposed which I feel would help blog maintenance run smoother.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/110998/152101)

Comment: Exactly +1 for reading the post and understanding it from a programmers perspective.  Another suggestion is if you don't want to use blog.stackexchange.com to host the "SE Company" blog, then put a link directly on the stackexchange website.  The stackoverflow website should have its own blog, it should be related to the stack site which in this case is programming stackoverflow.com

Answer (score 2):

http://blog.stackexchange.com/ works, y'know.

We mark it as `blog.stackexchange.com` on all of the Stack Exchange 2.0 sites that don't have their own blogs (since they go to their own blogs instead). It's only on Stack Overflow that we link to `blog.stackoverflow.com`, and in the end, it's the same destination anyway. For Stack Overflow, it still is their primary blog, so we label it as such when coming from there.

I believe there has been mention that basically, there are tons of programming blogs out there - a lot of Stack Overflow regulars and experts run their own blogs. To that end, creating yet another programming blog for them is just detracting from their normal blog portfolio. That's why we don't use Stack Overflow's blog as a programming blog. For those interested in reading the articles of their fellow programmers, you would want to visit Eric Lippert's actual blog, or Jon Skeet's actual blog.

I hear that Programmers has been thinking about a blog, though.

Comment: I guess this is not the answer I am looking for.  Please again read my post.  My post is stating that (and I understand this) for newcomers coming to stackoverflow they get to the site.  They see on the bottom a link that says "Blog" and it has a shiny red new button.  So they might think cool, not only is the site about programming but their is a programming blog.  They click on it only to be presented with a blog entry about Home Improvement, or about how to destroy enemies on call of duty 3.  It doesn't logically make sense.  Stackoverflow should have its own programming blog.

Comment: ...(cont)..Just as all the other stack exchange sites have their own blog stack overflow would be great to have a programming related blog.  I'd love to read a blog entry by Eric Lippert or one from Hans, or even from Mark G / Jon Skeet.  They are programmers, we are on stackoverflow, so why isnt the blog about stackoverflow.  As I said before I can understand that in the old days stackoverflow was the "company" but now its part of stack exchange.  The blog on stack overflow should be moved to the main stackexchange site.

Comment: @JonH I forgot the second half of my answer, eheh.

Comment: I disagree with your second half, I think it will benefit the community to have a nice group of blog entries from different programmers from the community.  I know a lot of the programmers on the stackoverflow site who don't have a blog and it would be nice and helpful to see their content.  I'm not trying to go to war here, I am merely making a suggestion.  Whether you, as stackexchange employees, agree or not is not my call.  I am just sayin...it would be nice.

Comment: @JonH I see the heart of your suggestion - we appreciate it. However, you shouldn't dismiss your own suggestion like that, even if we currently are at disagreement.

Comment: Jon Skeet has a blog? Wow!

Comment: @GUIJunkie http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/, found neatly tucked into his profile page. ♪