# Stack overflow blog top bar is unpopulated

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, top-bar, blog

On the Stack Overflow blog ( https://blog.stackoverflow.com ) the drop down for the Stack Exchange is unpopulated.  This seems rather odd in the layout and wording.

[image]

That said, *should* this even be on stack overflow or should there be a blog.stackexchange.com (thus why it is on MSE rather than on MSO)?  Note the text behind that dropdown:

[image]

Compare with the drop down from another blog enabled site that shows the associated community (note: `$site.blogoverflow` rather than `blog.$site`):

[image]

So...

Possibilities:

1. Move blog.stackoverflow to blog.stackexchange (related: [Move the Stack Exchange blog to blog.stackexchange.com](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/115302/move-the-stack-exchange-blog-to-blog-stackexchange-com) )
2. Associated blog.stackoverflow with meta.stackexchange.com
3. Make the communities drop down populate stack overflow related sites

Comment: I don't think the top bar should be there in the first place, it's not possible to be logged in (the blog is not a Stack Exchange site) so it's pointless to begin with. Most likely a design overlook that slipped by.

Comment: @ShadowWizard thats indeed another option... though the top bar kind of makes some sense when you *can* get to an associated community for the blog.

Comment: @ShadowWizard Nope, by design. See my answer.

Comment: @Anna fair enough, rare case of "agree to disagree" then I guess.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

blog.stackoverflow and blog.stackexchange are the same thing. There is no site associated with the company blog, so at the moment the "site switcher" just shows a pointer to the site list. We also don't necessarily want to drive folks to Meta from the blog, although that may happen later on as we see how Meta is getting used.

As Shadow Wizard notes in the comments, it's impossible to log in on the blogs the same way you can on a Q&A site, so we can't show notifications and whatnot, but Jeremy's plan was to keep the topbar as consistent across all our sites as possible. This is why we didn't just update the look of it on the blogs (did you know that there *was* a topbar on blogs before? :)) but also implemented a rather stripped down version of the site switcher.

That said... the wording does come off a bit weird. I'll drop the word "other" from it to make it more fitting.

Comment: Hrm, now I'll have to consider making Data Explorer completely consistent. :P

Comment: Well, I think that in this case simplicity beats consistency. Plain link or logo back to the "main" site should be enough, no need in the whole top bar, black and empty. :)

Comment: @shadowwizard I personally prefer not having a dropdown there, but Jeremy won this one. :)

Comment: I know why he won, it's because you lost your cat!

Comment: Tangental - something to think of when looking at 'what site do we want people to hit' - `curl http://blog.stackexchange.com/feed/` shows pages back for `<atom:link href="http://blog.stackoverflow.com/feed/" rel="self" type="application/rss+xml" />` and `<link>http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/04/putting-the-community-back-in-wiki/</link>` - its more a consistency thing. (Do you want me going here or there, and if its there, it should be *there*, not kind of there...)

Comment: @MichaelT Not sure what options Wordpress offers in this regard. Ideally, I think our blog should primarily live at blog.stackexchange.com, but I'm not sure what's involved in making that happen off-hand.

Comment: @AnnaLear I certainly agree with that bit - blog.stackexchange would fit better. Just one of those branding things that might be done better.