# Image scaling on Blog Overflow?

Tags: bug, status-completed, blog-overflow

I'm trying to write a post for Cooking's new blog, but when I try to insert an image, all size options (except for "full size") are disabled. The full-size is 1097 × 1462, and the thumbnail, medium, and large sizes are all set less than that under Config->Media.

Is there something that I need to do to get scaling to work, or is this a server issue?

edit: According to [a support thread on the wordpress site](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/wp-not-resizing-images), this is caused by gd not being installed on the server. (And a bunch of other links say the same thing, too.). So sounds like a server issue.

Comment: Ill take a look at installing gd on the server for you, it shouldn't be a problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've installed libgd and php-gd on both nodes of the cluster running the wordpress network. Image scaling is up and running now.

Comment: Seems to work for new images, I guess it scales when you upload them. Easy enough to re-upload. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Blogoverflow uses Wordpress, so it's a bit difficult for Stack Exchange to fix things like that. The easiest solution (and what I usually do for blog posts) is to just resize images manually to the desired size before uploading.

Incidentally, if you're interested in seeing better blogging features better integrated with the site, check out this proposal: [Using the Stack engine for the blog – a long-term idea for maintaining a healthy blogging culture](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/110998/using-the-stack-engine-for-the-blog-a-long-term-idea-for-maintaining-a-healthy/)

Comment: That doesn't work so well when you want to have it clickable to enlarge. Well, you could make it work, but then you'd have to manually upload two sizes, and deal with setting a custom link each time. Googling around, its *supposed* to work, but apparently gets grayed out e.g., if you don't have gd installed on the server. http://wordpress.org/support/topic/wp-not-resizing-images

Comment: Hm. In that case, perhaps they just need to install gd.