# Don't push [stackoverflow] tagged blog posts to the rest of the SE Network Bulletin Boards

Tags: feature-request, blog, community-bulletin

The recent blog post about Stack Overflow elections is definitely something to be known about, just not to all 80+ sites.

Maybe in keeping with allowing the whole community to be involved with SE updates while at the same not being too localized on SO, could these blog posts (ones that are tagged [stackoverflow] at https://blog.stackoverflow.com/) be filtered out from the bulletin board?

Otherwise it relies on each community updating their events, blog posts or meta with featured posts to push out these items. And some communities are not that active to do this easily.

Answer (score 6):

[Maybe Stack Overflow should have its own blog, and the Stack Exchange blog should be separate.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/110998/using-the-stack-engine-for-the-blog-a-long-term-idea-for-maintaining-a-healthy)