# Stack Exchange Blogs Compromised and Passwords Reset

Tags: support, blog, blog-overflow

Some of our WordPress instances were exploited yesterday at 11 AM UTC. We noticed that the compromise had taken place today and took the blogs offline as soon as we noticed. We have since restored the WordPress files from backup* to a new set of servers. Using our logs we were able to identify the exploit used as a vulnerability in timthumb.php which was included in a theme installed on our wordpress instances and we have removed the theme.

What does this mean to you as a user? If you have an account on one of our blogs then your password has been reset. However, if you have used the same password on other sites then you should also reset that password on those sites.

We apologize for this inconvenience and breach of trust. We will be using more rigorous security procedures around our blog network going forward.

*The database backups were failing but we did have a backup of all the files. We manually combed over the database to find any signs of damage but were unable to find any.

Comment: Will also be emailing all users that had blog accounts shortly

Comment: `timthumb` eh? I knew Tim Stone had to be involved!!!

Comment: Would the email accounts that signed up have been taken with the passwords? (I would certainly assume so)

Comment: @BenBrocka: From what we can see it was all bot activity. We don't know that the password hashes and emails were actually taken. However, they would have had the opportunity to get both emails and password hashes.

Comment: Possibly related: [Using the Stack engine for the blog](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/110998/1438)

Comment: Which kind of hashes did the WP installation use? Which algorithm and were they salted?

Comment: @MadScientist: The default MD5 multipass + salt, we have changed the salt: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_hash_password

Comment: @KyleBrandt MD5 is not a good choice for a password hashing algorithm.

Comment: @blahdiblah I don't think Kyle chose MD5, and I doubt it was implemented recently. I think everyone is aware there are better algorithms available.

Comment: The real problem is a programer of a plugin used in a theme thought this was a good way to check string equality: `if (strpos (strtolower ($url_info['host']), $site) !== false)`

Comment: @Zypher I hope you've submitted this codebase to The Daily WTF.

Comment: @AaronBertrand No doubt, but given that he mentioned changing the salt, I wanted to make sure that changing the algo was also on the radar.

Comment: @animuson I strongly deny that I would ever willingly touch WordPress.

Comment: Did anyone else with steam accounts under the same email address receive a password reset on the steam account shortly after the time of breach?

Comment: @blahdiblah I'm not sure I interpreted "we have changed the salt" the same way you did. We changed the salt today based on this exploit, or we changed the salt n years ago when we first implemented the blog?

Comment: [info on the exploit](http://markmaunder.com/2011/08/01/zero-day-vulnerability-in-many-wordpress-themes/)

Comment: @AaronBertrand: We changed the salt today as a result of the compromise. As per the checklist in this post: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/19696/verifying-that-i-have-fully-removed-a-wordpress-hack

Comment: @KyleBrandt Though perfect security is impossible, it feels a bit wrong that the checklist for recovering from a hack is the one used for the *last time* you were hacked.

Comment: @blahdiblah That was a personal blog of Jeff's, not one run by SE. The main initial response was to identify the exploit used and remove it as well as building new servers. We are going to be looking and more stuff around wordpress security going forward. So our actions so far were the minimal we felt we needed and could do in order to bring the sites back up.

Comment: Reading the info on the exploit, on *every* directory under the web root which is writable by the web server, please add `php_admin_flag engine off` (or equivalent for the server/php you're using). …. or better yet, default it off, and only turn it on for the directories that need it.

Comment: @DarthAndroid nope

Comment: What's the purpose of voting on this 'question'?

Comment: @JayRiggs to rep-cap Kyle, obviously.

Comment: @Jay, for me: I very much appreciate the openness.

Comment: Shouldn't this be migrated to meta.stackexchange?

Comment: @ScottPack For all intents and purposes, this *is* meta.stackexchange.

Comment: @AnnaLear You've stumbled upon the entire point of my bringing it up.

Comment: Maybe it's time to ditch wordpress and [create a good, integrated blogging platform for Stack Exchange](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/110998/using-the-stack-engine-for-the-blog-a-long-term-idea-for-maintaining-a-healthy).

Comment: @ScottPack I'd rather we get a real SE blogging solution before splitting MSO and MSE...MSO is significantly less of a usability nightmare and security risk

Comment: @BenBrocka Having never assessed the blogging infrastructure,  I can't speculate. I and many others do, however, actively avoid this mSO. Though I suspect my initial snide remark has rather taken us off track.

Comment: Wordpress (at least the Blog.SU setup) has always been a horribly buggy mess, so I'm not surprised. But I'd have thought that the people running it and one of the largest programmer communities would have thought a second or two about security...

Comment: Just for the record: Timthumb is not and never was part of WordPress. It isn’t even allowed in themes hosted on wordpress.org.

Comment: Having read an article relating to the GitHub's vulnerability and how it was exploited, this comes as a no surprise.