# Supposed SE is acquired and shut down, then we lose all the knowledge contained here?

Tags: discussion, content, backup

The content that is being generated by SE might rival one day with that contained in Wikipedia. While I can download the Wikipedia at any point and make sure that effort is not going to be lost, I'm not sure about SE. Is there any policy covering this? (I'm confident many users have the same concern, but could not find the question formulated in any way.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose that happens.

Thank goodness Stack Exchange thought about that already and planned for it by producing a quarterly [data dump hosted at archive.org](https://archive.org/details/stackexchange), containing all the posts, their history, comments, users and so on (all anonymized).

Comment: Now SE makes all the sense!

Comment: Well, that still means losing up to three months worth of data. :)

Comment: @ShadowWizard - better than all of it ;)

Comment: While at it, what about DRP? Does SE got such a thing?

Comment: I am assuming you mean this kinds of [DRP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disaster_recovery_plan), @ShadowWizard ? We have backups and another data center (which is only a few minutes behind).

Comment: Yes, I thought I saw something on MSE about it in the past, but can't find it now.

Comment: @ShadowWizard - possibly this: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/207653/se-backup-how-where-when-what-level

Comment: Partially, but [this](http://everythingsysadmin.com/2013/03/what-does-stack-exchange-do-wh.html) is what I was looking for - too bad it got no details. :(

Comment: @ShadowWizard The expected value drops down to 1.5 months. Still, a huge amount of work...