# New Badge Idea: Blog Contributor

Tags: feature-request, badge-request, blog-overflow

This badge would be awarded for contributing to the blog with an article. Your piece would have to be in the published status to qualify.

Comment: Stack Overflow doesn't have its own community blog though. :(

Comment: Also, who is in charge of choosing which blogs get published? If it's the moderators, then I have to say I can't support this; it would only cause problems.

Comment: It might also be nice if it can be earned more than once.

Comment: @animuson Usually there is someone appointed to be the blog promoter, and that person reviews submitted blogs and publishes them. At least on the SCIFI.SE this hasn't been an issue.

Answer (score 8):

This sounds like a good idea - everyone likes badges. However, from what I know the SE blogs are not running on the SE engine but on Wordpress. So the accounts are probably not linked and thus that badge would have to be awarded manually.

However, according to some meta post it is actually planned to use the SE engine for the blogs - *then* such a badge would be a really good idea and not require any manual interaction.

Comment: `However, according to some meta post it is actually planned to use the SE engine for the blogs` Hm? Link?

Comment: @YannisRizos it's [status-jeff-likes-the-idea-but-nobodys-bothered-to-implement-it-yet](http://blog.superuser.com/2011/06/30/installing-the-optical-bay-hdd/).

Comment: The accounts are linked now, Wordpress is using SE's credentials (except for the SE blog itself). I have no idea if there's any kind of two-way communication there though

Comment: FYI @ThiefMaster, there's a new authentication system for the blog (basically a wordpress plugin) that does link it to your network account, so theoretically it would be possible.

Comment: @YannisRizos I *think* ThiefMaster is referring to this: [Using the Stack engine for the blog – a long-term idea for maintaining a healthy blogging culture](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/110998/using-the-stack-engine-for-the-blog-a-long-term-idea-for-maintaining-a-healthy/121145#121145)

Comment: Exactly. I thought it was [status-deferred] or [status-planning] though...