# Don't display [stackoverflow]-tagged blog posts on community bulletins network wide

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, stack-exchange, blog, community-bulletin

[image]

All sites which don't have their own blog are notified of every blog post on blog.stackoverflow.com (which is run by SEI, not by the community, and contains both SO-specific and network-wide posts).

It's quite annoying to have irrelevant posts show up in the community bulletin (not to mention ones with titles in caps that grab everyone's attention). In this specific case, most of the people who see this won't be eligible to vote, and even if they were, you may not *want* votes from them (for an election, one prefers informed votes, not votes from people who visit the site once a year and have the bare minimum rep for voting). ([See also](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2013/03/2013-so-moderator-election/#comment-75462))

The blog engine already has a tagging feature. I propose that the community bulletins take posts from blogs in the following manner:

- If the site has its own community blog, show all posts from that blog
- If the site is Stack Overflow, show all posts from blog.SO
- If the site is *not* Stack Overflow (regardless of whether or not it has its own blog), include all posts from blog.SO which aren't tagged [stackoverflow](/questions/tagged/stackoverflow)

Comment: The caps were specially annoying http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2013/03/2013-so-moderator-election/?cb=1#comment-75428 .

Comment: Anonymity of votes still applies to meta, as does asking downvoters for explainations.  Those comments are still *noise* (even on meta) and not necessary/are deleted.

Answer (score 3):

FWIW, sites that *do* have their own blogs won't show posts from the SO blog at all... So it *already* works sorta like how you describe.

That said, I agree the current system is *less than ideal* - blog.so is a mix of things that pertain to the entire network, might be of passing interest to the network (new hires / misc company info), and SO-only announcements.

We'll *hopefully* be working on [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/110998/using-the-stack-engine-for-the-blog-a-long-term-idea-for-maintaining-a-healthy) in earnest fairly shortly - it's a brilliant idea that's long overdue. That seems like a perfect time to redesign the way the various blogs fit together with each other and the main sites.

Regarding the tagging suggestion: IMHO it would make more sense to exclude posts that aren't tagged with either the name of the site or [stackexchange]. Of course, we don't actually *use* tags that way right now, but we could, and that would allow for posts that are relevant to more than one site (but not the whole network) or specific to one site *and* generally applicable to the whole network. Otherwise, this just ensures the next bit of whining will be in response to a Super User post.

**Update:** current behavior (as of 2017) is as follows: posts tagged with [stackoverflow] will show up only on Stack Overflow and Meta Stack Overflow; posts tagged [company] will show up everywhere. If a post is tagged both [stackoverflow] *and* [company], it shows up everywhere. "Everywhere" is defined as "all sites except those versions of Stack Overflow dedicated to not-English languages".

Comment: Yeah, but just a minority of the sites have their own blogoverflow. Regarding shlck's proposal: Yay! A collaborative environment may be just what we need on Physics to get a steady blog.