# Featuring blog posts to specific sites

Tags: discussion, feature-request, blog, community-bulletin

I was in a question in [Academia](http://academia.stackexchange.com), when I noticed the featured Blog site at the right (Sorry I don't provide an image with a free-hand red circle):

> Blog
>
> Stack Overflow Podcast #98 - Scott Hanselman Is Better Than Us
>   at Everything
>
> Benefits for Developers from San Francisco to Sweden

While I am interested in one of these topics I am not sure it is of general interest for the community of Academia or [Pets](http://pets.stackexchange.com).

Could the featured posts be advertised only in the communities where it is relevant? Maybe if a post should be displayed in a site should be discussed in each site's meta.

[**Related**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/171278/247279): But it seems (I think) that we need a better filter/tool

Comment: Think of StackOverflow as your older brother and the featured blog posts as noogies you are obliged to take.

Comment: @Won't There's a whitespace in Stack Overflow, [which is actually a tab](https://twitter.com/clipperhouse/status/818497816834281472).

Comment: @zaq noogies inbound.

Answer (score 3):

The [Stack Overflow Blog](http://stackoverflow.blog/) is the **company blog**, not the Stack Overflow site blog.

The company name [was changed from Stack Exchange to  Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.blog/2015/09/were-changing-our-name-back-to-stack-overflow/) back in September 2015, which can indeed by somewhat confusing. (Stack Overflow is a single Q&A site in Stack Overflow network of sites.)

So what does it all mean? That the blog hosts all kinds of posts, which can be about many various things related to the company itself. While not all of those will be relevant to any site in the network, some would.

In theory, the bulletin can be enhanced so that site moderators will be able to edit its contents on a specific site, but it would probably cost many hours of development time, and I don't think it's worth the efforts.

If someone is not interested to see specific parts of a page, userscripts can be used to hide those parts, same way there are adblockers. But in my own opinion, the developers time is better spent on other things, that would benefit all users, not just small part of them.

Comment: How are the salaries of developers in Sweden relevant to the people who is in the pets site? Is this "relevant to the whole network of sites"? Why do you think it is not worth the efforts?

Comment: @Llopis See my edit.

Comment: @Llopis in contrast, another recent post on that blog was about Winter Bash.  Some posts are more interesting to any given person than others, but that's true of anything that appears in the bulletin.  Developer salaries are probably interesting to (in addition to SO) Software Engineering, Server Fault, Web Applications, Unix & Linux, Game Development, DBA, Information Security, and more.