# Enhance the current locking mechanism for moderators

Tags: discussion, deleted-questions, moderator-tools, historical-lock

In the interest of making the internet a better place, some time ago a feature was added whereby old, off-topic questions that had stellar information in them could be un-deleted, and locked, with a message that read in part

> This question exists because it has historical significance, but **it is not considered a good, on-topic question for this site**, so please do not use it as evidence that you can ask similar questions here.

A good example of this in action is with the [strangest language features question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1995113/strangest-language-feature)

I think we should allow a broader range of locking behavior for other valuable, yet off-topic questions that aren't necessarily of *historical value*.  In particular, when looking through my favorites list, I was sad to see that [this question on Backbone.js vs. KnockoutJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5112899/knockout-js-vs-backbone-js-vs) (Stack Overflow 10K only) was deleted.  Trying to figure how Backbone and KnockoutJS compare/complement each other is an **extremely** common search for web developers, and the top answer to this question is simply the best of anything I can find from Google—which is why I favorited it.

Ideally, I'd love to see this question undeleted, locked, but with a message that says something to the effect of:

> This question, while off-topic for Stack Overflow, was asked in bygone times of looser standards, and happened to acquire great answers before being deleted.  In the interest of making the internet a better place, it is being left open, and locked.  **Do not** use the existence of this question as evidence that you can ask shopping questions on Stack Overflow; you can't.

Comment: Side question - can anyone tell me why the KO versus Backbone question claims to need 2 more undelete votes, but when I try to vote, it tells me a mod has deleted it, and can't be undeleted?

Comment: Gordon probably became mod *after* the 8 votes were cast.

Comment: @Mysticial - ouch - what a sneaky bug *that* is.

Comment: In any case, +1 for this idea. The C++ book question can definitely use this. At least until tag wikis become a suitable replacement for it.

Comment: I'd have to say no.  You're basically asking to dilute the efficacy of locks.  Adding new lock reasons or whatever just means that we'll slap them on more things, which is definitely what we *don't* want.  A line in the sand has to be drawn somewhere.

Comment: Also, the old adage of "if it's *that* important to you, host it somewhere else" still applies.  Nothing is stopping you from taking it and hosting it *somewhere else*.

Comment: @casperOne: I've heard that adage for the longest time now - has anybody brought up the fact that hosting off-site isn't going to change the hundreds of existing links still pointing to SO that are now broken? Maybe we need a feature that lets us create custom redirects from question IDs to off-site locations.

Comment: @BoltClock'saUnicorn Honestly, I've *never* been concerned about that.  The web was designed from *day one* to be resilient to this, when the resource doesn't exist on the other side of that link.  To be honest, it's not as important as everyone thinks it is.

Comment: @casper - your first comment begs the question.  *Why* do we not want more things opened and locked?  Is the purpose of SE to make the internet a better place, or is the purpose to blindly follow some arbitrary rules at all costs?

Comment: @casper - as far as hosting these questions myself, [come on now](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/124342/why-were-some-historical-non-constructive-questions-undeleted#comment332822_124342)

Comment: Considering common misspellings, I wonder how many people would honestly think "looser standards" means "loser standards".

Comment: @AdamRackis SO has said, from day one, that not all content, and not even all programming content, is appropriate on the Q/A model.  Some questions, even very good questions, just can't be effectively addressed on this site.  Saying that it doesn't hurt anything to leave it undeleted simply isn't true.  When people see questions like this they try to emulate them, especially when they have hundreds of upvotes.  People also try to add content, usually not of particularly high value to such questions, if they can't they get upset and come here asking for it to be reopened...

Comment: If you leave more things opened and locked, then what's the purpose of having it at all?  The lock is for the already *exceptional*.  If you lock *more* things, then you're degrading what is *exceptional*; it's not very exceptional if there's so many of them.

Comment: @Servy - I don't think I said that leaving it undeleted wouldn't hurt anything.  I'm saying we need to have more nuanced, subtle, intelligent ways of not deleting good information, while also not giving the impression that these questions are on topic.  I think this proposal strikes a reasonable balance.

Comment: And for hosting the questions yourself, a Wordpress.org account or whatever the kids are using these days?  I don't see how people typing over and over into meta asking for this is easier than just copying and pasting into a blog somewhere.

Comment: @casper - agreed.  Locks should only be for *exceptional* content.  My point is that not all exceptional content happens to be of *historical significance*.  I'm just saying that content can be exceptional for other reasons, and the current locking protocols don't reflect that.

Comment: Off topic, Adam, but the bullet list in your profile seems a little... off ;)

Comment: As a non-moderator, I approve of this request.

Comment: @casper - honestly, if stellar content like this is going to be  hosted on AdamRackis.wordpress.com then it might as well be deleted; more 10K users would probably see it on SO than would ever browse to my blog :)

Comment: @Servy: In this particular case, the question has over 100,000 views... imagine how many people this question has *helped* in the past. It is really right that people have stopped benefiting from this post, because of the off-chance someone comes across the question and decides its an example to create a similar question?

Comment: @BoltClock - how so?

Comment: @Matt You're assuming this is the only repository in the world that compares backbone to knockout.  It just means that since this resource doesn't exist they'll go to another one instead.  If someone hosts this information externally they could even be finding the same information, just not on Stack Overflow.

Comment: @Adam Rackis: The bullets are being pushed to the side and getting clipped as a result. AFAIK this is usually caused by `<li>` tags not being wrapped in a `<ul>`...

Comment: @Servy: Yet the reason *everyone* goes to Stack Overflow is because the *other* sites on the Internet do it worse, have wrong information, or are unreadable. Yes, there will be *somewhere* else which *might* have the same content, but we should be *preserving* good information.

Comment: @Matt The reason that SO has such great content, and can therefore be *the* place that programmers go to to find good information, is because it is restrictive in the types of questions that allows on the site.  If we didn't restrict the scope of the site then rather than having even more good content, we'd just have a whole lot more crap to sort through to try to find the gems, thus making it harder for people to find good information.

Comment: `but we should be preserving good information.` - exactly, that's my whole point.  Everything else is just noise.  **STOP REMOVING GOOD CONTENT**

Comment: @Servy - that's a straw man.  Nobody is saying that we should loosen our standards.  The point is that old, existing, good content should be dealt with in a more intelligent manner than *deleting it*

Comment: @Servy: What Adam said. We prevent link only answers in case a) the site goes down, and b) to be the source of information. If we start deleting 1000+ voted, 100,000 viewed questions, we, ourselves are becoming the rotting links.

Comment: @BoltClock - I don't know what unholy html parsing thingy SE uses, but if I wrap those LIs in a UL, everything goes to hell (I lose my anchors).  Which is probably why I did it that way to begin with.  What browser are you using where things are getting clipped?

Comment: @AdamRackis By saying that we should allow content that the site's standards say is out of scope then we are, by definition, loosening our standards.

Comment: @Adam: Odd... try using Markdown for your list instead? I'm using Firefox.

Comment: @Bolt - thanks - I see it now.  I've been meaning to update my profile anyway, so I'll try to see if I can fix it.

Comment: @Servy - I don't think we should legislate to the internet's lowest common denominator.  If we keep **good content** like this open and locked, with a banner explicitly saying that this question is off topic, but being preserved only for the sake of the information, and a user chooses to ignore that and ask crap, then so be it.  You can't fix stupid, as Ron White said, and SO has *very* effective systems in place to remove new, off topic questions.

Comment: @AdamRackis And yet in the past there have been a *lot* of people emulating these questions and then pointing to them when their questions are closed/deleted.  Because of this there was a big push to delete all but the very best such questions and to use historical locks very sparingly.

Comment: @Servy: Again, however many people you're talking about ("citation needed" BTW), it's *nothing* in contrast to the people who can now no longer use that resource because we're deleting them.

Comment: @Servy - were these questions out in the open at the time, or were they historically locked?  I'm not on MSO **that** much, but I've honestly never seen someone whining about their dumb question being closed, while pointing to the (historically locked) strangest language features question.  And as Matt said, your focusing on only one aspect.  Yes, you can try to **minimize** the number of bad questions asked, but you'll be killing **good information** in the process.  We need a better balance, which I think locking achieves fairly well; this request seeks only to expand that process a bit.

Comment: As I said before, this is not the only resource on the internet comparing knockout to backbone.  There are other resources, other sites, other content, or even other places that can theoretically host this exact content if it is indeed as valuable as you think it is.  So no, it's not "Killing good information", it's just choosing not to host is here on this site.

Comment: Would modifying the question to be more along the lines of *"What's the difference between Backbone.js and Knockout.js, and what should I consider when determining when to use one over the other?"* be enough to get it undeleted and possibly reopened? I agree, that top answer is great.

Comment: @Rachel - I'd post that comment under Shog's answer.  He can probably answer best.

Answer (score 9):

> Trying to figure how Backbone and KnockoutJS compare/complement each other is an extremely common search for web developers

Sure. And how much longer do you think that two-year-old answer is going to remain relevant to them if it's *locked?* Assuming it's still accurate *now*, of course.

Everyone wants that royal road to research results. "I haven't defined my problem yet", they think, "but it would sure save me a lot of time if someone just gave me the solution now anyway". They should totally drop that line of thinking and <s>try jQuery</s> ask specific questions.

That being said, I realize you're not just proposing this change for *this* specific question. So ask yourself this: if you have an answer worth preserving, an **answer** that offers on-topic, constructive advice useful to many readers... Why not just write an on-topic, constructive question to go with it? You could edit the original (closed, deleted) question, or even post a new one and then suggest that a moderator merge the two thus preserving the original answer... Without trapping it in amber as an immutable historical artifact.

Comment: Thank you for the thoughtful answer.  I do realize there's an issue with obsolescence: maybe KnockoutJS will change next week.  I think there are all sorts of creative solutions we could use for that, but I wanted to keep the question as simple and narrow as possible.  On that note, though, maybe we could start to make CW relevant and useful again, and apply it so situations like this?

Comment: Moreover, we shouldn't forget that, yeah, lots of other sites may have content that attempts to answer this question, but the beauty of SO is that we have some incredibly gifted users, as evidenced by the fact that this particular question continues to have the best answers in town.  Finding a way to allow it to stick around in an **unobtrusive way** would have considerable benefit.

Comment: I'm kinda coming around to ---Jeff's--- [slhck's idea](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/110998/using-the-stack-engine-for-the-blog-a-long-term-idea-for-maintaining-a-healthy) that we need a properly-integrated blog engine for moving this sort of thing into when it isn't likely to be salvaged. We'll be looking into this a bit further in the coming months.

Comment: That would be incredible.  Are you thinking something like an SE—Wikipedia, that's editable by the community?

Comment: Guys, look. Shog is letting himself be influenced by Jeff's ideas (ideals?). That makes Jeff still sort-of in charge, right? Right?!

Comment: @Shog9 If I edited that specific question to be more along the lines of *"What's the difference between Backbone.js and Knockout.js, and what should I consider when determining when to use one over the other?"*, would that be enough to get it undeleted and possibly reopened? (I [asked this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/178670/enhance-the-current-locking-mechanism-for-moderators?noredirect=1#comment539441_178670) under the main question, but Adam suggested I comment here instead since that's something a moderator would have to answer). I agree that the top answer there is great.

Comment: That still sounds like a very broad question, @Rachel. If you want to take a crack at editing, I'll undelete - but expect it to be re-deleted at some point if it doesn't get re-opened.

Comment: Thanks @Rachel (and Shog) - I think I can polish that question a bit, so I'll take a crack at it.

Comment: Thanks Shog. @AdamRackis I made a quick edit to it, but feel free to edit it further if you think it needs it. The edit I did was mostly with the top voted answer in mind, and I tried to keep much of the OP's wording. I mainly moved the focus to Backbone vs Knockout, and removed the broad request for any other frameworks.

Comment: @Rachel - there wasn't much to add.  Honestly I really don't think the Grollia vs Shark analogy applies to this question.  Thoughts, Shog?

Answer (score 6):

I think that the historical lock should be really be a temporary state. The idea of keeping those pages around is that doing that is a disservice to the internet at large because it's a repository of good information. Okay, but then it's a disservice to the internet at large to have that information:

- in a Q&A format that's just *not suitable* to the kind of information at hand
- in a locked state that people haven't been able to contribute to for years and won't be for the foreseeable future.

Ideally, the information in those pages should find new houses. Either in a community Stack Overflow blog (why is that still not a thing that exists?), or in some sort of off-site community-run wiki site, or in other already existing places such as Wikipedia. It depends by the kind of question, really. Once this has happened and the information has been refreshed, the old boring stale copy on Stack Overflow should finally rest in peace.

**Historical lock should be a temporary state** that questions should linger around in for as little time as possible. It's, at best, a kludge; "this question is here but pretend it isn't! We don't do this stuff anymore! Please take a gander and leave as soon as possible. Gremlins are here."

In other words, what we need is *less* historic locks, not *more.*

Comment: YES!  I've mentioned this before.  Historical locks are nothing more than delaying the inevitable heat death of these questions.

Comment: @casperOne: Not sure if intentional pun (since historical locks are said to "freeze" questions and answers).

Comment: I love everyone who posted/commented on this answer! (Especially me!)

Comment: dawwwwwwwwwwwww