# The Stack Overflow Conspiracy - don't tell Jeff I'm on to him

Tags: discussion, fun, jeff-atwood

Judging from the fact that there's been a lot of talk of venture capital being pumped into Stack Overflow lately, something hasn't been sitting well with me at all. Then I got to thinking.

Ever think about Jeff's user ID? It's [1](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1/jeff-atwood). Seems innocuous, right? Like maybe he was the first user or something? But no, think about it. Jeff could have had any user ID he wanted. He could have had 1337 or 3735928559 or even -4. But those would have been too obvious for most conspiracy theorists. Jeff is a more subtle man than that.

For Jeff is even more devious than **two** [Wilson Fisks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kingpin_(comics)). You see, 1 is the atomic number of [**hydrogen**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hydrogen). And what is made of hydrogen? Well, a lot of things. So we need to narrow it down some more.

Fiddling with some more numbers, we come to realize that Jeff's name is "Jeff". But that's short for "Jeffry". That means he's missing two letters off of his name. His ID is 1, and he's missing 2 letters. [Deuterium](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deuterium) is hydrogen, having an atomic number 1 but an atomic mass of 2.

So what is the main use of deuterium? Nuclear fusion! Fusion is also the name of a **chocolate bar**. A really, really good chocolate bar. Oh man it's loaded with caramel and those little puffed rice things. Those little puffed rice things are sold in big blue boxes called [Rice Krispies](http://www.ricekrispies.com/).

Unless I'm crazy (which I assure you I am not) Rice Krispies consort with marshmallows to produce the [hybrid](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hybrid_(biology)) Rice Krispie squares. Now, how can marshmallows, which are round, be combined with Rice Krispies, which are cigar-shaped (not unlike [UFOs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unidentified_flying_object)), to form *squares*. Obviously it's the [law of sines](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_sines), which allows mathemagicians to create squares from circles and triangles.

Cosine and sine are abbreviated to `cos` and `sin` in mathemagical expressions. Clearly, then, it is a sin to create Rice Krispie squares. But more importantly, Wilson Fisk, the roundest man alive, is a sinner: The rounder the man, the more of a sinner he is.

Knowing this, we must conclude that Jeff is trying to use enormous amounts of deuterium to power a marshmallow-based graviton emitter to make himself look less round through [gravitational lensing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gravitational_lens). By looking less round, people will mistakenly believe that he is not a sinner and therefore trustworthy. People will not stop and think that he is covering something up.

So what is he trying so desperately hard to cover up? *The very fact that he is trying to cover something up.* His devious self-referencing loop of lies has finally been exposed! No more will my fellows be confused by this convoluted web of mystery. I have prepared a graphical representation of this coding horror as my master stroke that will blow Jeff's plans out into the open:

[image: THE WORLD IS A LIE]

Comment: You should try and make yourself some chocolate crackles by the way. Out of Rice Bubbles.

Comment: **I'll have whatever he is having!!!**

Comment: You need a hobby.

Comment: @square: *this* is his hobby.

Comment: @squid: I have a hobby: identifying conspiracies.

Comment: Wow... ....... ....... wow.

Comment: ah... the joy of friday

Comment: @Jon: I know. It really had my gears grinding for a while until I pieced it all together.

Comment: I think Jeff is going to have to change his user ID to -4 to disprove the allegations.

Comment: @Pekka: that would only confirm them.

Comment: Actually, there is a factual error here. Jeff is short for "Jeffrey" (or possibly "Jeffery"), which means he's *three* letters short. That in turn points us to *tritium* instead of deuterium; and on the Wikipedia page for tritium, I found this... interesting sentence: **"cleaning tritium from the moderator may be desirable after several years to reduce the risk of escape to the environment."** The precise meaning of that sentence I leave to you, but it's clear this runs much deeper than we'd thought.

Comment: @mmyers: **My God...**

Comment: Oh my God. The poor souls who we elected moderator a few weeks back. What will happen to them? Are they still alive?

Comment: @Pek: I hope not!

Comment: @voyager: I've had some, and it's great!

Comment: @Ether in that case, you shouldn't drive today. It will wear off in about 8-12 hours.

Comment: Slow day at work?

Comment: @AnonJrMints: Very.

Comment: Mmmm, JrMints...

Comment: +1 this is the best thing I've read on Meta in a while

Comment: @NIfE: You could be the next Sir Arthur conan doyle Mr.Sherlock :). Great post.

Comment: **WAIT!** I'm user number 1337. I can't believe I've been a member of this conspiracy the *whole* time.

Comment: Hydrogen is not a noble gas, so I'm afraid your whole conspiracy theory is in tatters.  You'll have to start again.

Comment: Hydrogen isn't noble -- **and neither is Jeff**! -- @Pollyanna is onto something!

Comment: Okay, this is getting big. Jeff's gravatar hash is 51d623f33f8b83095db84ff35e15dbe8, which translates to the decimal number 108779348342750472702867132401906473960. The digit sum of this number is 166, which is... well... **4** x 42 - **2**

Comment: My user ID thing has really disturbed me, too.  I'm not sure that it's a conspiracy, though I keep losing things ever since I started visiting this site.

Comment: Could someone on Windows please see if holding down Alt while typing 108779348342750472702867132401906473960 gives us any special symbol?

Comment: @Arjan: Φ <- first try. Φ <- second try. Got the same one twice in a row. That's a capital phy, which is used in combinatorics to denote a generating function. It's also used in trans-real arithmetic to denote "nullity". Nullity is a horrible thing, just like Jeff. Coincidence? Doubtful.

Comment: Oh, I see. You've started learning Python.

Comment: @tinkertim: it's not the Python, it's the medicine cabinet.

Comment: Wow. I just read this and I could hardly stop laughing.

Comment: Did anyone notice that you can make squares with triangles and no circles?  Hydrogen is a circle.

Answer (score 81):

[image]

Comment: See? Look how sinful he is.

Comment: Nice one! He looks decidedly evil.

Comment: Dude.  This is disturbing.  :)

Comment: It looks fake 'cuz you forgot to add the rain to his face. -1

Comment: If you look closely, you can see it's fake. Or maybe Hollywood is failing with their special effects and Jeff is _in front_ of the rain.  Holy crap, it _is_ a conspiracy!

Answer (score 27):

As for conspiracy: *why* does xkcd happen to mention the number 1 just [today](http://xkcd.com/710/) as well?

[image]

Comment: This is terrifying.

Answer (score 26):

He's not the only one...

[image]

Answer (score 25):

Nah, what conspiracy?

User 1, aka user one, aka **Neo**.

**6** uper **U** ser
**6** erver **F** ault
**6** tack **O** verflow

Answer (score 12):

> The Stack Overflow Conspiracy - don’t tell Jeff I’m on to him.

Dear Jeff,

He's on to you.  ***Run!***

Comment: -1! I said **not** to tell him!

Comment: @NIfE - Hey, I know which side of the trilogy my rep is buttered on.

Answer (score 6):

[The Number ONE. http://img299.imageshack.us/img299/9724/numberonen.jpg](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Number_23)

Answer (score 4):

Wait, wait, that was the rationale of SO? !! oohh gee and I always thought trying to conceal he was Craig: http://images.google.com/images?q=David%20Anthony%20Higgins

Answer (score 3):

Fear question 1 asked by user 1!

[Should meta.stackoverflow.com replace uservoice.com?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1)

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/badges/1 is not too bad though!

Comment: @Arjan: that doesn't make sense...