# What questions should NOT be asked on Meta?

Tags: discussion, meta

It seems to me like there is some confusion as to what can and cannot be asked on Meta.

For example,

**Can**

- Why does x not work?
- What the heck does Welbog's avatar mean?
- Will x be implemented?
- Is Jeff Atwood a vampire (I have evidence)?
- Is there a way to do x?
- I just killed Jon B with a pony-mounted laser, what is the best practice for hiding the body?

**Cannot**

- If I kill Batman will I become Batman?
- Why does SO not have x feature that y site has?
- Why did I lose x rep?
- User x is posting spam, what to do?11!
- Why am I not as cool as Welbog?

**Definitely cannot**

- Which is better, unicorns or waffles.
- Why are Welbog and Jon B vandalizing my questions?
- Why don't we all downvote Jon Skeet and see what happens?
- What happened to Rich B.?
- When will Jon Skeet reach x rep?
- What questions should NOT be asked on Meta?
- What is your Google Wave ID?

I realize this is partially covered in the FAQ, but there is still some confusion. Stuff is still getting posted that ought not to.

So please summarize for me, in the best way you can, what should NOT be discussed here.

Comment: ........   this one :p

Comment: @Ran: C'mon, I'm asking an honest question.

Comment: I think this is a valid question, but some realistic "Cannot" examples would help this from being closed...

Comment: Okay. Give me a couple minutes to think of some.

Comment: There. Hope that's better. Feel free to edit if you think of others.

Comment: Your new examples aren't really cannots. "Why did I lose rep" is a valid support question. Any discussion about features is fine. Questions about how to handle spammers are fine.

Comment: That was Welbog that added "that question", for the record.

Comment: @Welbog wins. :)

Comment: I like where this edit history is going.

Comment: Sigh... 10k users...

Comment: All in a day's work, citizen! You're safe from harm now, @George, now that The Encapsulator is your protector!

Comment: But... what exactly *did* happen to Rich B?

Comment: @Rand - banned for one year.

Comment: @Jon: Why was that...?

Comment: @George - that's not for me to say, and it's really none of our business.

Comment: @Jon B: Sorry, that was meant to be tongue-in-cheek.

Comment: Why is this question pointless?

Comment: And I bet this was closed because Welbog got at it.

Comment: @George: On the contrary! I gave the question a reason to be read!

Comment: @George - I voted to close early on because the tone of the question seemed "pointless".

Comment: I just killed Batman but I did not become Batman...what gives?

Comment: @MrLister: I've been here for nearly 3 years and still don't quite have 10k.

Answer (score 3):

From the FAQ:

> **What kind of questions should I not
>   ask here?**
>
> Avoid asking questions that have
>   nothing to do with the above websites.
>   This is not a random discussion board,
>   this is a place for improving our
>   community and websites!

**Further:**

- Questions about specific users are generally frowned upon.
- Anything the community considers "pointless" (including jokes).

There are exceptions to every rule, but these are few and far between.

Comment: Then how come "Jon Skeet Facts" is still open?

Comment: "generally frowned upon". The Jon Skeet Facts question is a rare example of a post about a specific user that the community considers worthwhile.

Comment: @George, It was a migration.

Comment: @George There's a [blog post](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2008/11/stack-overflow-is-you/) that covered why the Jon Skeet Facts were kept.

Comment: What about some of the others? Like the "StackOverflow Conspiracy"?

Comment: I'm not familiar with that one, @George. However, examples of exceptions to the rules do not invalidate the rules.

Comment: Jon - Here you go: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/41288/

Comment: Oh yeah. I tuned that one out.

Comment: @Jon Yes it invalidates it when the exceptions out number everything else and Im willing to bet its much closer than you think.

Comment: @Locutus Outnumber everything? There are 11 thousand questions on Meta. Probably no more than 3% of them are these exceptions. Only ~1800 non-deleted questions are closed.  We have a lot more on-topic questions than not-on-topic.

Answer (score 2):

Don't ask questions that make it look like you're bored (unless it's Friday).

Comment: But every day of the week before Friday is when I'm the most bored

Comment: (Or unless you add freehand circles)

Answer (score 2):

People who hang out on Meta more than a little — i.e. too much — know that it's looser than the "real" sites; see [shameless plug for my FAQ proposal](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/47634/how-are-the-rules-different-on-meta), where I encourage you to add to the discussion.  Depending on the day new users come to Meta *cough Friday cough*, they might get a skewed impression of the site.  Specifically, what gets lost sometimes is the **true purpose of Meta: discussion about how SO-family sites work and suggestions for how they can be improved**.

The items in your <strike>"Cannot"</strike> "Definitely cannot" list are out-and-out jokes, or at least intentionally silly.  Jokes aren't banned, but they don't support the true purpose of Meta, either.  Meta is not officially [the Third Place](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/04/do-trilogy-sites-need-a-third-place/).  So yes, go ahead and joke if you like, but if the community doesn't consider a given joke to be funny, don't expect it to get upvoted or even stay open.

The edge case is Rich B.; that's just disallowed because it's considered a private matter for that user.

EDIT: The items in your "Cannot" list are instances where the user should have read the FAQ before rushing to post, and/or dupes.  But they're usually answered satisfactorily before being closed.

Answer (score -4):

No question can escape being relevant in the infinite suck hole that is META!!!!!

Comment: Why did you change your name, Chacha?

Comment: @George Happened after several "-1 for tradition" comments

Comment: @cco: There has been a recent string of name changes...

Comment: @George It will be returning Jun 10 2010

Comment: @Tradition @Chacha are you **trying** to lower your rep?

Comment: @rlb.usa Well, you are successfully lowering yours :)