# Why is Jeff Atwood still listed as CTO?

Tags: bug, status-completed, stackexchange.com

I like Jeff so I'm not knocking it, but why is he listed as CTO in the [about page](https://stackexchange.com/about/management) if he left the company?

Comment: @Lix - I am not suggesting kicking him out.  I guess I'm really into correct data, if he's gone he's gone - why would you keep reference of something that doesn't exist?

Comment: Well - he was last seen on the site (MSO) [10 hours ago](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/1/jeff-atwood) and his last [answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/124643/how-can-meta-be-made-more-conducive-to-discussions/125309#125309) was yesterday.  I don't believe he will disappear at all :)

Comment: W​​​​​h​​​​​o​?

Comment: Still listed as CEO - possibly a mistake - perhaps a transition period is the reason behind this.

Comment: @mm - too soon...too soon...

Comment: Also, does he [still have a veto...](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/70061/i-propose-changing-the-term-closed-out-for-something-else#comment337719_70061)? ;-)

Comment: Closed by the moderators who close just about everything.

Comment: Yeah, those despot moderators... They're nothing but trouble.

Comment: [It's a conspiracy...](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/41288/the-stack-overflow-conspiracy-dont-tell-jeff-im-on-to-him)

Comment: Post reopened by Popular Demand.

Comment: @Spolsky - you've got this great system called stackoverflow/meta that you don't even use.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Jeff Atwood is no longer listed in https://stackexchange.com/about/management.

However, he is listed as co-founder in https://stackexchange.com/about/team and mentioned in https://stackexchange.com/about.

Comment: I don't think they're planning on wiping the memory of his involvement from existence, so he can probably stay on the `/about` page =)

Comment: +1 for `/about/team` but -1 for `/about`.

Comment: Hes no longer listed because I made this post, he sure as hell was on there a few days ago.

Comment: @JonH I do not doubt that. Just stating what currently is the case.

Answer (score 6):

[Yannis had it right](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/41288/the-stack-overflow-conspiracy-dont-tell-jeff-im-on-to-him). I can't reveal any details without forfeiting my own life, but suffice to say, there were Templars *and* Zombie Unicorns involved. Oh yes. This rabbit hole goes deep...

It **definitely wasn't** due to a simple oversight resulting in that page being *chock full* of crufty, out-of-date information. [That's what *they **want** you to think...*](https://stackexchange.com/about/management)

Comment: And he gets to keep his ♦?! :)

Comment: -1 - Posted a serious question - why is it that a mod has to post something that he/she feels is funny.  How about a serious answer?  if I posted this as an answer it would been closed, downvoted, locked, etc.

Comment: @JonH: You left a comment yesterday asking for an answer, so here's your answer. If you don't like the humor, that's fine - I didn't particularly like the direction comments were headed in either. I do appreciate you bringing this up, since that page did need to be updated, but if you're getting seriously worried when it takes a couple days to update a bit of background information that, frankly, very few people ever read... You could use a bit of humor.

Comment: @Shog9 - I don't get seriously worried.  I'm very much into common data and "automatic updates" have you.  You have a central system in place that contains "common" data so there shouldn't be a lapse in something like that.  If I went to the presidents website the day after Obama was elected and it still showed Bush as the president its plain wrong.  This was the same case...not that I am pro obama or bush..just saying.

Comment: No, I understand. Like I said, that page had gotten woefully out of date, and should have been updated regardless of whether or not Jeff was still here doing his thing. I think there was a plan in place to re-do it as part of a larger project (they're doing some photo shoots in NYC right now), but updating it sooner didn't hurt.