# At which time the reputation loss shows up in reputation log?

Tags: bug, stack-overflow, reputation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [71,000 + 85 = 71,084?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/157324/71-000-85-71-084)

At which point in time a reputation loss will show up in the log: At the day a certain post has been removed or at the day the reputation had been awarded initially?

Background: Today I started with a reputation of 1646. Then I suggested two edits (both accepted) and thus climbed to 1650. I then downvoted two answers, my reputation went down to 1648. So far so good. One of those answers got deleted, the reputation log shows +1, yet my total for now is 1647 instead of 1649.

I am now wondering where the other -2 came from. From another post that has been removed after I suggested an edit as on Dec 10?

I looked at my [reputation history](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1521227/spontifixus?tab=reputation) with the show removed posts flag set.

For the record: Here is my Reputation log (as of 12/17/2012. 15:19 UTC):

[image]

And the pop up when hovering over my username in the titlebar:

[image]

Comment: I noticed more than a few reports recently of -1 instead of +1 when downvoted answer got deleted. Do you have link to the deleted post?

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd This was the question in question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13914786/how-to-get-line-count-in-a-file-without-reading/13914827 (As a <10k user I don't see deleted posts...)

Comment: Hmm.. can't see anything unusual. It all happened today; post was normally deleted by owner after getting single downvote; Sure you don't see anything else in your reputation history page?

Comment: When you hover your username on top you see the recent reputation changes; what you see there?

Comment: I'm having the same issue with posts that I have flagged today resulting in me losing a point rather than regaining the point used to downvote when a moderator deletes them. Put simply, I do not get the downvote point back once the post is removed.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd I see no rep changes for today even though I have lost 2 rep through this issue (on main SO site).

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd I edited the question and added screenshots of the reputation log as well as of the popup when hovering over the username

Comment: @Spontifixus I believe that the downvote points are not being readded upon post deletion. They record is being removed from the reputation history though. I'm having the same issue.

Comment: @Ren: Thing is: One of the posts I downvoted has been removed. The other one still exists. The +1 for the downvoted shows up in my log. Nevertheless as I wrote, in the total calculation of my rep today there's a "-2 report" missing somehow...

Comment: Well I am missing 2 points also today. I was at -3 but I've since gained a point back through a deleted post so I am inclined to agree that this may not be the issue.

Comment: @Ren yes they are readded, I downvoted a post today, it was deleted and I got the rep point back just fine. I don't think that's the issue here, more likely older post deleted.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd: If I understood Manishearth correctly rep changes due to deletion of an older post should show up in the log the day the deletion occured. Right? (Just to confirm that this could be a bug and not some misunderstanding on my side...)

Comment: @Spontifixus yes, but I just recalled something that can explain what happened. When a post you downvoted that was deleted is getting **undeleted** you will lose the rep point again and the only place it will appear is in the original time of the downvote. No trace whatsoever in the time of undelete as far as I can tell.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd sounds OK on first sight - but still if there would be two downvoted posts (one of them undeleted) my total should have been 1648... Can you (or another mod) have a look at the deletion history of that posts?

Comment: Problem is we can't know which posts were undeleted, doubt mod can know such thing either. As for the question you linked to, nothing wrong there: one post is indeed removed and you got +1 for that and the other is still there with your -1 intact..

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd Seems that someone of the SE staff needs to have a look at that...

Comment: I think this might be the same issue as what described here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/157324/71-000-85-71-084

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd I think you are right. Though one cannot say for sure with extensive database digging - which is like using a sledge hammer to crack a nut... So I will vote to close a duplicate of the question mentioned...

Answer (score 2):

No, the rep loss is displayed in the day the loss occurred<sup>1</sup>

Go to https://stackoverflow.com/reputation, scroll down, and click the rep recalc button. That *ought* to fix it. Otherwise, it's a bug.

<sup>1. Interestingly, though, rep changes due to deleted posts are considered to have happened in a way such that the post never existed at all (i.e., the loss is counted on the same day as the gain/vice versa) when the system internally determines if you've hit the rep cap.</sup>

Comment: I didn't realise the [/repuation](http://stackoverflow.com/reputation) recalc button actually did anything since the [big reputation update](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/123319/recent-reputation-history-changes)?

Comment: I never hit the rep-cap, thus deleted posts should show up on the day they got removed, correct? I clicked the rep recalc button with no success, so I will retag this question as bug...

Comment: @Spontifixus: The deleted posts _always_ show up on the day they were removed. I'm saying that the system _internally_ treats them as different when it needs to calculate rep caps/etc.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying!

Comment: @Matt: It _shouldn't_ do anything, but it's still the magic button that all systems have that seems to fix all problems (eg "reboot your pc"). The other day it fixed a rep bug with a user of mine on Physics.