# Wrong information in post metadata

Tags: bug, sidebar, metadata

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [“Yesterday” time specification shown when it was actually the day before yesterday](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/127668/yesterday-time-specification-shown-when-it-was-actually-the-day-before-yesterd)

When viewing the [last question I asked](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/158955/195761) I notice a bug in the side bar of the thread displaying the metadata:

[image]

The question was asked yesterday (2012-12-17), yet the metadata still shows today (2012-12-18)

Comment: Likely, it means "in the last 24 hours"