# "closed" indicator does not show up properly in chat onebox

Tags: bug, chat, closed-questions, onebox

I recently posted a onebox link to a [closed question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/41288/the-stack-overflow-conspiracy-dont-tell-jeff-im-on-to-him) in chat. I noticed one weird thing, though: the "[closed]" indicator does not show up in the chat onebox:

[image: The Stack Overflow Conspiracy - don't tell Jeff I'm on to him (no "[closed]") at end]

I'm expecting a similar problem to happen with "[on hold]" for recently closed questions and "[duplicate]" for duplicate questions. Is not showing the "[closed]" indicator in a onebox by design, or is it a bug?