# Don't encourage me to do things I can't really do (aka don't ask me to edit or comment on locked question)

Tags: feature-request, closed-questions, locked-questions

When a question is closed (not as dupe) we see such message below the question:

> [image]

Encouraging us to edit or leave a comment is awesome in most cases but sometimes questions are also locked, e.g. [this one](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/41288/the-stack-overflow-conspiracy-dont-tell-jeff-im-on-to-him).

Clicking "edit the question" link leads to friendly "This post is locked and cannot be edited" error message, but still - that link shouldn't be there in the first place, same way there's no ordinary "edit" link on the locked post.

Clicking "leave a comment" just cause the page to scroll upwards, with no actual result.

Can the whole last sentence ("If this question can be reworded...") please be omitted in case the question is locked?

Comment: Can the person who asked the question still edit or leave a comment though? I'm not sure if that's possible or not but I always took it as a hint to the OP to fix it, not others.

Comment: @PeterJ no, only mods can edit such questions and as for comments, I think even a dev can't post comments on locked post. (of course he can unlock it for a short while, post comment and lock again :))

Comment: +1 for this... the wording definitely needs a change here.

Comment: @HackerKarma thanks, the last sentence simply has to be removed, can't think of a wording that won't be confusing.

Comment: Same [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/961942/55075).

Answer (score 9):

**I agree that it shouldn't suggest you to edit or comment on a closed message, but I disagree with removing it completely.**

I think the last sentence should stay, but be reworded in locked questions to reflect that rewording closed questions is something you can do, but it's not possible on the current question because of the lock. Something along the lines of

> If *a closed* question can be reworded to fit the rules in the help center, please edit the question or leave a comment. *However, this question has been locked: editing and commenting is disabled.*

(Emphasis on changes)

The close messages were one thing I used to learn how to use the site, but I only read each close message fully once or twice. If that time the question had been locked, I would not have seen that small and useful message.

The message doesn't have to be what I suggested, it's simply a push in (what I think is) the right direction.

Comment: Fair point, +1 from me... can be viable solution as well. :)

Comment: How about hiding the message when the functions are not applicable to the question?