# How to open a closed question?

Tags: support, closed-questions, vote-to-reopen

I asked a question on "How to help a postgraduate student to write a book" on Academia Stack Exchange on July 1. Unfortunately, a moderator of that site had closed it the same day. How can I reopen that question again?

Comment: https://www.academia.stackexchange.com

Comment: I can't see your question. Maybe it's deleted.

Comment: You need to ask about this on the [academia site's own meta](http://meta.academia.stackexchange.com/):

Comment: @inɒzɘmɒЯ.A.M the question is locked and you can see it [here](http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/48142/how-to-help-a-postgraduate-student-to-write-a-book)

Comment: @James it's because his a/c has been deleted from there... I just posted answer to his post below... oh wait I didn't notice his meta.SE a/c also removed too.

Comment: @HackerKarma Yeah I suspect this user requested to be, across all sites.

Comment: @Hack most likely OP deleted his/her own account, usually if requested it takes several days. Self deletion is instant. (assuming user didn't contribute much)

Comment: This question has been asked multiple times on Academia.SE and other sites (see [1](http://academia.stackexchange.com/q/48142/), [2](http://academia.stackexchange.com/q/47503/), [3](http://academia.stackexchange.com/q/49696/), [4](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:http://hsm.stackexchange.com/questions/2573/how-to-help-a-postgraduate-student-to-write-a-book)). Each time, users post comments asking for clarification. Each time, the OP deletes his/her own account and never comes back to edit/clarify the question.

Comment: Writers, too, and the user now *preemptively* deletes the account right after asking.  Early instances were accompanied by spam answers, so we always delete these as spam (seeds).

Answer (score 4):

The question is here: https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/48142. It isn't locked, it is put on hold. Since the question was migrated and the migration was rejected because of the question being put on hold, the question is no longer open for editing or reopening.

The only thing OP can do is do another try with a question that is both clear, narrowed down enough and on-topic on Academia. Then it can be answered.

Comment: Patrick, I see the question is locked... see my answer below.

Comment: Oh great, it's the migration limbo....

Answer (score 2):

The question is definitely **locked**.

The question "[How to help a postgraduate student to write a book](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/48142/how-to-help-a-postgraduate-student-to-write-a-book)" was ***migrated*** first then later the migration was ***rejected*** from hsm.stackexchange.com Jul 1 at 2015-07-01 13:36:32Z. The closed message says:  "closed as ***too broad*** by Kimball, scaaahu, jakebeal, gman, Mad Jack Jul 1 at 2015-07-01 13:36:32Z"

Here is the screenshot of the same:

[image]

But, if you click on the **[edit the question](https://academia.stackexchange.com/posts/48142/edit)**, it says "This post is **locked** and cannot be edited." Here is the screenshot of the same:

> [image]

**P.S.**

I just noticed that OP's both user accounts are deleted i.e. "user2528" (Academia) and "user302106" (Meta.SE). I would also like to include the following comment posted by user [ff524](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/254250/ff524) under my answer as:

> The OP actually posted this identical question [many times](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/263347/how-to-open-a-question-that-has-been-closed-already#comment856680_263347). Most are
>   deleted at this point, only this locked one is still visible. So the
>   answer to the OP's question is deeper than just this one issue with a
>   locked post.

Also, the bottom of the current "closed" message does points to the help article where it says:

> If this question can be reworded to fit the rules in the [help
>   center](https://academia.stackexchange.com/help/closed-questions).

The [help center](https://academia.stackexchange.com/help/closed-questions) article has a good explanation on what does it mean if a question is "closed" or "on hold"? but the last line of the help page says: (emphasis mine)

"There is functionally no difference between an [on hold] question and a [closed] one; neither can be answered until it is re-opened, **but they both allow comments, votes and edits.**"

This is kinda little confusing as one can not *edit* the question which is currently in the *locked* mode.

Comment: It was rejected because it was closed. And it wasn't locked as in the usual lock a moderator does. It is locked in the sense the post is rejected and not editable.

Comment: @PatrickHofman Thanks. But, which "closed" did the OP saw, is it the same one that is currently displayed?

Comment: @Pat well, the final outcome is a lock, it doesn't really matter for the OP what caused it, I upvoted your answer because it contains valid tip how to "resolve" this, but the dry fact is that it's locked.

Comment: @ShadowWizard At the bottom of the "closed" message(added to my answer), it gives the "help center" link. I don't know the reason for as the question is locked?

Comment: @Hack I am well aware of that and even [started a feature request](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/211632/dont-encourage-me-to-do-things-i-cant-really-do-aka-dont-ask-me-to-edit-or-c) to change this confusing behavior.

Comment: @ShadowWizard wow... that's been pending for 1.7 years... Interestingly, the last lines of the Help page says: "There is functionally no difference between an [on hold] question and a [closed] one; neither can be answered until it is re-opened, but they both allow comments, votes and edits." -- notice "they both allow comments, votes and edits"...

Comment: @Hack true, "on hold" and "closed" got nothing to do with "locked".

Comment: @ShadowWizard so the "please edit the question" link should be change to what user "3ventic" said in his answer.

Comment: The OP actually posted this identical question [many times](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/263347/how-to-open-a-question-that-has-been-closed-already#comment856680_263347). Most are deleted at this point, only this locked one is still visible. So the answer to the OP's question is deeper than just this one issue with a locked post.

Comment: @ff524 Thanks for pointing that. I have added note about your finding in my answer as comments are not searchable, can not be edited or can become hidden as more gets added.