# Is the Q&A format really suited for Meta?

Tags: questions, answers, meta, discussion

Many posts here are of the kind "I have this idea, do you like it?", "I found this bug, it should be fixed" or "I'd like this feature to be implemented".

How suitable is the Q&A format for such posts?

There are no "good" or "bad" answers, and there's no clear mechanism to say "I like your idea", "I acknowledge this bug" or "We'll implement this"; "traditional" answering, up/downvoting and accepting just doesn't cut it here, in my opinion.

Maybe something else should be provided, aside with the standard Q&A format (which, quite ironically, is instead perfectly adequate for *this* post).

Comment: Related, possible dupes: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1/should-meta-stackoverflow-com-replace-uservoice-com, http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18811/two-months-on-is-meta-working-as-a-replacement-to-uservoice

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is a meta for?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/240440/what-is-a-meta-for)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course it's not ideal. But it *is* our own dogfood.

Answer (score 5):

<sub>How cute, he just discovered Meta today and wants to change everything already because it would work better.</sub>

Joke aside, the Q&A works also for this site.

It's not ideal, especially for discussions, but it motivates then to be more concise and less "blablating". You can't fall into a "10 pages" discussion that nobody wants to read since beginning, because the only way to "chat" is by comments. The fact that this is limited actually helps, in my opinion, to not fall into useless and endless arguments.

Also, you don't need to post "I agree with you". You can just vote to express the fact that you agree (or disagree).

Comment: Just for your information, I didn't discover Meta today... that can be seen by anyone in my profile. I just don't like to do things only for the sake of it, so I didn't participate actively until I found something I was actually concerned about, like voting on Area 51. Or how to have a discussion here.

Comment: @Massimo - I apologize for the joke, then. Didn't mean to offend you in some way.

Comment: Joke aside (no offense, don't worry): don't you find it a little disturbing to have to use *comments* to discuss something?

Comment: I agree with you  :)

Comment: @Massimo - no, I don't. Someone posts his opinion on the discussion, people can answer directly to him. It doesn't disturb other "flows" of discussion, then.

Comment: Perfect example: Earlz, with **whom** are you agreeing exactly? :-p

Comment: @Massimo - he [didn't use the "@"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work), so I guess with the one who is automatically notified of the answer, the one who posted. Me, in this case.