# Show an indicator when an answer (or comment) is deleted for users without moderator tools privilege

Tags: feature-request, deleted-answers, notification-bar, deleted-comments

When a user without moderator tools privilege (10K on most sites) opens a link to deleted question ([example](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1/)), they will see 404 page, which is clearly showing that the post is already deleted.

> [image: 404 page]

However, when they open a link to a deleted answer ([example](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/251026/clear-indicator-when-an-answer-or-comment-is-deleted-for-users-without-moderat/251027#251027)) / comment ([example](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/251026/clear-indicator-when-an-answer-or-comment-is-deleted-for-users-without-moderat#comment819571_251026)) on existing question, they will only see the question. There is no clear indicator that the link is supposed to be a deleted answer/comment.

I guess this is not a problem for experienced users, since they will notice it by:

1. Looking at the URL and see if it's an answer/comment or not (indicated by post ID after the title, then
2. See if the browser doesn't auto-scroll to any post (well, unless the connection is laggy)

But still, I believe it'd be better if SE shows a notification to show that the answer/comment is already deleted, perhaps looking like this?

> [image: deleted answer notification]

One of the reason why I think it'd be useful is for spam/offensive answer hunting on chatroom. I understand that these flags should be used very carefully. When flagging spam question, there's no problem since you cannot flag if it's already removed. But for spam answer, there is a possibility that the user will think that the question itself is a spam if the answer is already removed (well, the onus is on the flagger, but with this feature, it can be prevented).

Comment: Used wrong keyword when searching for this feature, didn't realize it's a dupe :(

Comment: All good, nice use of the new self-dupe-hammer! ;)

Comment: +1 for using the new close feature. :)