# Is it possible to find answers by ID?

Tags: support, answers, post-id

It's possible to find questions by ID by going to `<site>/questions/<id>` (which automatically redirects to `<site>/questions/<id><question name>`), but I don't know how to search answers by ID. Part of the reason is that answers seem to have an entirely different ID format than questions. For example, the first question asked on Meta Stack Exchange is located at the following URL:

```
https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1/should-meta-stackoverflow-com-replace-uservoice-com
```

but the first answer to that question is located at:

```
https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1/should-meta-stackoverflow-com-replace-uservoice-com/130#130
```

There have been several times where I've had the post ID of an answer, but was unable to find it because I don't know how to find an answer by ID. How can this be accomplished?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The "canonical" way to find answers by ID is

```
https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/<answer ID>
```

It is also the URL that you'll be presented with when you click "share" to the bottom-left of an answer, with your user ID if you're logged in.

In fact, these "non canonical" "answer by ID" URLs will also work

```
https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/<answer ID>
https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/<answer ID>
```

All of them will automatically redirect to

```
https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/<question ID>/<question title>/<answer ID>#<answer ID>
```

Answer (score 3):

This can be done fairly easily. Just go to:

```
<site>/questions/<answer id>
```

and it will automatically redirect to:

```
<site>/questions/<question id>/<question name>#<answerid>
```

which will bring you to the exact answer you're looking for.

Additionally, going to:

```
<site>/posts/<answer id>/revisions
```

will bring you directly to the revision history, from which you can press "Return to Answer" to return to the answer.