# Are there any plans for celebrating the 10th anniversary of Meta Stack Exchange?

Tags: discussion, meta, fun, swag

Is there any plan for Meta Stack Exchange's 10th anniversary?

The [first question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/1/) was posted on Meta Stack Exchange on June 28, 2009.

A few months before, Stack Overflow celebrated their 10th year anniversary by creating the [anniversary page](https://stackoverflow.com/anniversary). Is there any similar plan for MSE, or any Swag Contest?

> [image: site is ten years old]

Comment: For a large portion of its life, this site was actually Meta Stack Overflow.

Comment: Wasn't there a [swag](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/318910/time-for-some-more-swag) party a couple of months ago? And then there was a hugely successful [cheese](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/316515/who-cut-the-cheese) competition.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Who cut the cheese?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/316515/who-cut-the-cheese)

Comment: @Mari-LouA The swag party for celebrating Stack Overflow's 10th year anniversary

Comment: @Mari-LouA Not a duplicate. That was about Stack Overflow's 10th anniversary; this is about Meta Stack Exchange's.

Comment: The competitions were held here. What do you expect, another swag fest for this meta site, which you yourself stated earlier, used be Meta SO. I don't think celebrating MSE per se is that significant a milestone, besides it's been already celebrated. Two competitions were held last year, here, on MSE.

Comment: [*Yes, we certainly can. Starting in the very near future, we're going to be writing some interesting posts here **and on MSE**. While **the network itself isn't turning 10**, its DNA (the realization that we innovated a better way to learn) has. And, our network sites do a great job of putting up with Stack Overflow getting all the shiny new stuff initially, so **they are getting their fair share of treats** at this party.*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/374617/happy-10th-anniversary-stack-overflow-commence-au-festival) Sep 27 '18 Looks like the answer is a "no".

Comment: But the team could be planning something up its sleeve, literally days before the site reaches its 10th anniversary....

Comment: @sonic It's 30 June and there was no celebration.